Is there a short syntax in javascript for a call chain containing synchronous and asynchronous methods of the same class?
I know of 2 ways that are not very convenient and look inelegant:

Via then:
(new TestClass).syncMethod().asyncMethod().then(self => self.anotherSyncMethod())

Via await:
(await (new TestClass).syncMethod().asyncMethod()).anotherSyncMethod()


I expect it to be something like this (pseudocode):
(new TestClass).syncMethod().asyncMethod()->anotherSyncMethod()
where -> is the transition from an async method to a synchronous one.
Is there something like this in JS, and if not, is there any plans for it in the future?

There is not.
However, the proposed pipeline operator might enable this in the future. You can find some bikeshedding in disussions there, like in issues #53, #86, #145, #189.
